# Python - Probability of 6 or more Tails/Heads Code

Tags: python, statistics, probability

I assigned my students in comp sci to write a code that simulates flipping a coin 100 times, storing the results in a list. Look for a streak of 6 heads ( or more ), or 6 tails ( or more ). If you find a streak, then consider the trial a success. Repeat this experiment 10,000 times. Use this to determine the probability of finding a streak of 6 heads or 6 tails.

Theoretically this probability should be ~80%.

EDIT: It is possible I misinterpreted this theoretical probability. I found this probability here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2736117/what-is-the-probability-of-getting-6-or-more-heads-or-tails-in-a-row-after-flipp

My code is giving me a probability of about 54%, the probability of getting exactly 6 in a row. However, if I got 7, 8, 9, or more in a row, my code should mark this as a success, correct?

I understand my code checks for steaks of 6, but if there is a streak of 7, 8, 9, ... it would still mark it as a success. There must be something I'm missing here...

Attached is my code:

```
import random
numberofstreaks = 0
for experimentnumber in range(10000):
    result = []
    for i in range(100):
        flip = random.randint(0,1)
        result.append(flip)
    
    for i in range(len(result)-6):
        if result[i:i+6] == ([0,0,0,0,0,0] or [1,1,1,1,1,1]):
            numberofstreaks += 1
            break
print(numberofstreaks)
print('Chance of steak:',(numberofstreaks/100))
```

Note: They are currently learning about lists, which is why their code must contain the use of lists.

Thanks ahead of time!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A slight correction:

```
import random
numberofstreaks = 0
for experimentnumber in range(10000):
    result = []
    for i in range(100):
        flip = random.randint(0,1)
        result.append(flip)
    
    for i in range(len(result)-6):
        if result[i:i+6] == [0,0,0,0,0,0] or result[i: i+6] == [1,1,1,1,1,1]:
            numberofstreaks += 1
            break
print(numberofstreaks)
print('Chance of steak:',(numberofstreaks/100))
```

The answer is now `80.22%`. `(A or B)` returns A, if A cannot be deduced to be false, otherwise B. A list of all `0s` isn't `False`. So you were only checking for streaks of `0s`.

Comment: Perfect, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

From what I understood, your code doesn't account for multiple streaks in a given 100 throws of a coin.
You can do that by shifting i by 6 places once it has found a streak so that it doesn't count a >6 streak as multiple streaks.

Comment: Perhaps I misinterpreted the theoretical probability. I did some research on this, and that is how I found the ~80%. That probability must allow multiple streaks in 100 flips then. So it makes sense that my probability would be different as I do not care for multiple streaks of 6...just if a streak of 6 appears in the 100 flips.